# I am trying to compare string literals and I want to remove repeated literals I want to do it without using POINTERS.,

Tags: c

I am trying to compare string literals and I want to remove repeated literals I want to do it without using POINTERS.

This is my code:

```
char str[30];

printf("Enter strings : ");     

fgets(str,29,stdin);

char tem[30];

int count , county;

for(count = 0 ; count < strlen(str)-1 ; count++) {      
    for(county = 1 ; county < strlen(str) ; county++) {
        if(str[count] != str[county]) {
               tem[count] = str[count];     
        }
    } 
}

//PRINT

for(count = 0 ;count < strlen(str) -1 ; count++) {

    printf("%c",tem[count]);

}
```

Input: `happen`
Expected output: `hapen`

Comment: I guess you cannot do that because array name as opeland of `[]` operator or function argument will automatically be converted to *pointer* and you use it.

Comment: What this code needs is a few more `strlen` invokes.  But hey, seriously, props for using `fgets` rather than `gets`. Not joking there.

Comment: There must be some way as I am able to access all the literals but I am not getting the proper logic. I know this is very easy by using * (asterisk) but I am not able to use the logic , well and I tried with this

Comment: Well, if the only purpose is to remove concurrent duplicates, you don't need two loops. Is that helpful? You also don't need two buffers.

Comment: if(strcmp(str[count],str[county])) tem[count] = str[count], but it's not woring.

Comment: How to do this without using two loops ? @WhozCraig

Comment: Simply `if(str[count] != str[count+1])` and get rid of inner loop.

Comment: I tried but I am getting the same string as I inputted via Keyboard . @LPs

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicated letters, or only consecutive occrrences of the same letter? Should "Mississippi" become "Misp" or "Misisipi"?

Comment: I want to make "Mississippi" as "Misp" @MOehm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correcting your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[30];

    printf("Enter strings : ");

    fgets(str,30,stdin);

    char tem[30];

    size_t count;
    size_t county=0;;

    for(count = 0 ; count < strlen(str)-1 ; count++) {
            if(str[count] != str[count+1]) {
                   tem[county++] = str[count];
            }
    }

    tem[county] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", tem);

    return 0;
}
```

Take note that this code remove double chars if this char have +1 displacement in the sting.

**EDIT**

To have `mspi` as output of entered string `mississippi`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char str[30];

    printf("Enter strings : ");

    fgets(str,30,stdin);

    char tem[30];

    size_t count;
    size_t county;
    size_t tem_index = 0;
    size_t size_of_string = strlen(str);
    bool found;

    for(count = 0 ; count < size_of_string-1; count++)
    {
        found = false;
        county = count+1;

        while ((found == false) && (county<size_of_string))
        {
            if(str[count] == str[county])
            {
                found = true;
            }
            county++;
        }

        if (found == false)
        {
            tem[tem_index++] = str[count];
        }
    }

    tem[tem_index] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", tem);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

To have `misp` as output of entered string `mississippi`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char str[30];

    printf("Enter strings : ");

    fgets(str,30,stdin);

    char tem[30];

    size_t count;
    size_t county;
    size_t tem_index = 0;
    size_t size_of_string = strlen(str);
    bool found;

    for(count = 0 ; count < size_of_string-1; count++)
    {
        found = false;
        county = 0;

        while ((found == false) && (county<tem_index))
        {
            if(str[count] == tem[county])
            {
                found = true;
            }
            county++;
        }

        if (found == false)
        {
            tem[tem_index++] = str[count];
        }
    }

    tem[tem_index] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", tem);

    return 0;
}
```

Take note that all these solutions are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, It's working for happen as I guess two literals are together but I tried with input : developer , I am not getting devlopr.  @LPs

Comment: well, I guess we know the answer to M Oehm's question now.

Comment: @DeveshPratap As I wrote, your code is what your code is supposed to do. If you want to do get rid of all repeated chars into a whole string, the code is different.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, we have... ;)

Comment: What is the supposed output for `mississippi`? Is it `m`? Or `mspi`?

Comment: I want to make "mississippi"  as "misp" @LPs

Comment: @DeveshPratap misp is weird. Shouldn't be mspi?

Comment: @LPs no, it should be `misp`.

Comment: Yes I guess it must be misp because we are getting 'm' , 'i' , 's' and than 'p', but I desperately want the logic , that's all.. for me anything will work, if its mspi or misp, @LPs

Comment: @DeveshPratap No time to post an answer, but take a look [here](http://pastebin.com/ZWfz7cn7). Gotta get some sleep.

Comment: @DeveshPratap I added the mspi solution.

Comment: Thank you !! have a tight sleep @WhozCraig

Comment: @DeveshPratap I added the `misp` solution too.

Comment: Thank you Sir @LPs

Comment: why we are using bool flag, any specific reason behind that ? @LPs

Comment: @DeveshPratap My personal explanation is that a `true`-`false` variable is needed. You can just use a `char/short/int` whatever kind of var

Comment: @DeveshPratap If you meant why are we using it: because of you need to trace the result of comparison. Based on the fact that a specific char is found you copy or not that char.

Comment: I understand that it is needed, but I know all the 1, 0 fundamentals , but I am curious to know why ? as in above solution what I was trying to do without flags , you achieved that solution just using the flags, any specific reasons ?

Comment: @DeveshPratap and LPs , Use 30 as `fgets`'s second argument, not 29.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thx, I edited. I didn't take care about that part of code.

Comment: I am trying to save every num character in char pointer, for that I am trying to allocate dynamic memory, logic is like, if num will increase, then malloc() will also increase and num will get copy in char pointer., I have posted my code, please take a look into that , thank you @LPs

Comment: @DeveshPratap The isn't an update code. BTW, if you have a new question, close this one checking as answered an answer and posta a new question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to remove allduplicates isn't quite there yet:

- You use the same indices for the new and the old string, but you need two different indices, because the new string is as long or shorter than the old string. If the old string is "aaab", your index for the old string is 3 when you see the "b", but the index for the new string is only 1. (By skipping indices you leave uninitialised gaps in your string.)
- You look forward to find other occurrences of the same letter, but you append to the new string for every letter that doesn't atch. You must look at all folllowing letters, but you must append to the new string only once. That is, you must make your decision whether the letter is duplicate or not after the loop, based on the information that you've found in the loop.
- When you look forward, you shouldn't start a 1, but at the letter after he current letter. If you start at one, you will find duplicates for every letter after the first, because you check each letter with itself.
- This is not an arror, but it's not a good idea to call `strlen` repeatedly in a loop. The length of the input string doesn't change, so you can determine the string length beforehand. If you just want to use it as your termination condition, you can test whethet the current letter is the null terminator.

Below is a solution that uses your logic, albeit by looking backwards, not forward. (If you look forward, you will copy the last occurence of a letter, if you look back, you'll copy the first occurrence. It may make a difference in the order of the letters. For Mississippi, you'll get "Mspi" or "Misp" depending on which strategy you use.)

The program overwrites the same string. This is possible, because you are filtering out letters and the new index is equal to the old index or smaller:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void remdup(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;      // index into old string
    int j = 0;      // index into new string

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        int k = 0;
        int dup = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            if (str[i] == str[k]) {
                dup = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (dup == 0) str[j++] = str[i];
    }

    str[j] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Mississippi";

    puts(str);
    remdup(str);
    puts(str);

    return 0;
}
```

This solution doesn't scale for large strings. A more effective method would be to keep a table of which of the 256 possible characters have already been used.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is helpful @M Oehm

Comment: I want to know the logic behind setting the flags, you mentioned 'dup' and its a flag, why we are using flags ?

Comment: Start with the assumption that there are no duplicates, hence `dup = 0`. Now look at all preceding letters. If a letter is equal to the curent letter, there is a duplicete: Set the flag and stop looking. (I've just noticed that the above code is too wasteful: It would be enough to look at the first `j` letters, because if there are duplicates, they must be found there.)

Comment: In such cases it helps to think about different ways to represent the condition: "Duplicate" means _any_  of the letters is a duplicate. Conversely, the negation or "not duplicate" is: _all_ of the letters aren't duplicates. A condition for all elements means we have to look at all elements. A condition for any element means we can cut the loop short once we have found one element. So the strategy is to formulate a condition by means of any element, assume it is false initially and the try to find an element which satisfies it.

Comment: I am trying to save every num character in char pointer, for that I am trying to allocate dynamic memory, logic is like, if num will increase, then malloc() will also increase and num will get copy in char pointer. I have posted my question , please take a look into that @M Oehm